# ngStorage $sessionStorage strange behvior, every user can see values user entered to the form fields

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

**Use case**: form, user enter some values to the fields go to other web-site, go back and get the form values entered before.

I used **ngStorage** and **$sessionStorage** for that, and binding works fine, except that other users can see saved values as well.
I mean when I go to my *localhost:3000* and fill in some values(chrome) I can see them updated in different browser(firefox) with the same address(*localhost:3000*).

So after I tried to deploy this to server, others can see what I put to the form almost like **!live** channel. This is not the desired behavior. I need some local/session storage **per user**. So when one user fills in some form others can't get those values. Is the way to use this ngStorage right way? What do I miss? Ideas?